# Customize Solidus library code - Address with optional phone number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, solidus

I am trying to override Solidus code and wanted to know what my options were?

In particular I am trying to change the Address to make the phone optional.

Answer (score 2):

Solidus aims to provide a better customization interface - [they want to avoid you opening up the Solidus/Spree classes](https://solidus.io/) - because it increases the chances that you break the system.

The original answer was broken for Rails 6.0 (Zeitwerk changes). [For Rails 6 there is untested example code taken from a github issue.](http://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/3651)

```
# app/decorators/your_app/spree/address/make_phone_optional_decorator.rb
module YourApp::Spree::Address::MakePhoneOptionalDecorator
  def require_phone?
    false
  end

  Spree::Address.prepend self
end
```

**Be sure to name the files `*_decorator.rb`, like this they will automatically been picked up by solidus.**

---

Original answer:

#### Alternatives listed from most to least preferred

1. To this end they provide [extension points](https://stembolt.com/blog/class_eval-and-the-terrible-horrible-no-good-very-bad-day/)

   - [which do not cover Addresses](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/v2.1/core/app/models/spree/app_configuration.rb#L277-L385).
2. Decorators

   - which doesn't help us because the address acts within Solidus library and not code called within our application
3. Module#prepend

   - Create a file under `app/models/spree` and prepending additional spree namespaces if required
   - Add the prepend into `config/initializers/spree.rb`
   - Prepend is an improvement on class_eval as you can call the non-overridden version of a method call with super.

In the actual problem - there is no extension for a Spree Address, a decorator won't work because we are not calling the code (say in a view we have written), so we need to change the Spree code with prepend.

app/models/spree/optional_phone_address.rb

```
module Spree
  module OptionalPhoneAddress
    # require_phone?
    #   - no longer require a phone
    #   - a * no longer appears next to phone in the view
    #
    def require_phone?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

config/initializers/spree.rb

```
#
# Customization of Spree Code
#

Spree::Address.prepend Spree::OptionalPhoneAddress
```

#### Note

- [there is a comment about removing the method call from the API](https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/v2.1/core/app/models/spree/address.rb#L136-L141)
- You have changed the behaviour of Solidus which should be tested
- Spree's google group suggested the way of fixing this by [opening the class with class_eval](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/mBitPeGz5wA) - I do not know if that is current practice with the new maintainers.

#### Further Study

- [class_eval and the terrible, horrible, no good, very bad day](https://stembolt.com/blog/class_eval-and-the-terrible-horrible-no-good-very-bad-day/)
- [Jordan Brough - Customizing Solidus at the Model and Controller Levels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imGuPzkOC3Y)
- [Why Solidus?](http://nebulab.it/blog/why-solidus/)

Comment: In latest solidus/rails (2020: Rails6, solidus 2.10) this does not work anymore (https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/issues/3651).

Comment: Thanks @Felix - I am not working with Solidus but I cut and pasted the example code from the github issue. Feel free, or other people working with it, to change the answer as you see fit.